# Bash скрипты запуска и останова python скриптов

Tags: linux, bash

Пытаюсь сделать bash скрипт запуска python скрипта - если он еще не запущен:

```
#!/bin/bash

workdir="."
script_name_ext="$1"


if ps -ef | grep "${script_name_ext}" | grep -v "grep" | grep -v "bash"; then
  echo "already on ${script_name_ext}!"
  exit 0
fi


script_name=${script_name_ext%".py"}

mkdir -p -- "${workdir}/logs"

[ -f "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log.9" ] && rm -f -- "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log.9"
[ -f "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log.9.gz" ] && rm -f -- "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log.9.gz"
for n in $(seq 8 -1 0); do
        [ -f "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log.${n}" ] && gzip -f --best -- "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log.${n}"
        [ -f "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log.${n}.gz" ] && mv -- "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log.${n}.gz" "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log.$((n + 1)).gz"
done

[ -f "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log" ] && mv -- "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log" "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log.0"
[ -f "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log.gz" ] && rm -f -- "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log.gz"
[ -f "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log.0.gz" ] && rm -f -- "${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log.0.gz"

/usr/bin/python -u ${workdir}/${script_name}.py >> ${workdir}/logs/${script_name}.log 2>&1 &
```

он работает, только смущает неказистый вариант условия:

```
ps -ef | grep "${script_name_ext}" | grep -v "grep" | grep -v "bash"
```

Можно ли как-то проще это написать?

Далее, bash скрипт остановки процесса:

```
#!/bin/bash

script_name="$1"
pid="$(pgrep -f "${script_name}" | grep -v $$)"

pgb="killing ${script_name} PID ${pid}"
cnt=0

while [ -n "${pid}" ]; do
  kill "${pid}"
  echo -ne "${pgb}\r"
  sleep 1
  pid="$(pgrep -f "${script_name}" | grep -v $$)"
  pgb+="."
  if [ "${cnt}" -ge 15 ]; then
    echo -ne "killing -KILL ${pid}\r"
    kill -KILL "${pid}"
    break
  fi
  cnt=$((cnt + 1))
done
```

вроде как он должен попытаться 15 раз послать сигнал завершения, если не удалось завершить - просто прибивать процесс. Но этот скрипт находит `pid="$(pgrep -f "${script_name}" | grep -v $$)"` находит тут сам себя и завершается с криком Terminated.

Подскажите, как правильно находить PID процесса по имени в bash скриптах, потому что просто выполнение инлайн в оболочке /bin/bash работает прекрасно...
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Спасибо!

Comment: Вроде в Ubuntu никуда не делся start-stop-daemon. Или можно unit файл написать для systemd.

Comment: unit файл - да, очевидное решение задачи. Его я и применил после Вашего комментария )), но всё же хочется победить bash....

Comment: просто сохрани pid запущенного скрипта в файл…